# Should I use a two-way ANCOVA or three-way repeated measures ANOVA on my data?

Tags: anova, ancova, two-way

I am trying to run a two-way ANCOVA on data from a multi-crossed design, looking at the effect of 4 treatments on the decay rates of 2 DNA target concentrations in moving water over time. Mesocosms were sampled at 8 time points after DNA additions. Is it even correct to run a two-way ANCOVA on this kind of data with "time" as the covariate? I have also come across a three-way repeated measures ANOVA that seems to fit my experimental design well as I could test if there is an interaction(s) between my treatments, DNA target type, and time on DNA concentration. How do I determine which test to use?

Comment: How many (longitudinal) samples do you have?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by longitudinal samples. Do you mean how many total samples did we collect over the time of the experiment? @dipetkov

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean. And in addition to the approaches mentioned, it might be worth it to consider approaches which model time dependence explicitly. Take a look at Ch. 7 of [Regression Modeling Strategies](https://hbiostat.org/rmsc/).

Comment: Thanks for the link! So between all mesocosms, treatments and time points, we collected a total of 160 samples @dipetkov

Comment: Note that if you measured 20 samples over 8 times points, that counts as 20 samples rather than 160. And did you take a measurement before the DNA additions? In fact it will be helpful to describe your data in some detail & even add a plot or two.

Comment: I am not placing my plots online, however, I am analyzing the LN(gene copy concentration) over time. It is decreasing. So I have 4 levels of treatments and 2 targets being analyzed across those treatments. My data being analyzed consists of separate columns containing information on time of sample (.33, 4, 8, 16, 24, 48, and 72 hours), LN(gene conc.), treatment type (4 levels), and gene target (2 levels). There were 4 replicates of each treatment type sampled between 16 mesocosms over the 7 time points listed. So 16 samples (regression slopes calculated) @dipetkov

Comment: I think I get the picture now: you have 4 experimental replicates for each treatment. (And are the treatment levels a different dose of the same treatment or different treatments altogher?) I suggest you update the body of your question with all this info, it's relevant.

Comment: I will update this in the actual question when I get a chance, but for now, yes 4 experimental replicates of each treatment and they are different treatments all together. Is it possible for you to give insight into my question whether or not to use two-way ANCOVA or three-way repeated measures ANOVA with the info I have given? @dipetkov